# What hypothesis for A is better than B?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am still confused about Hypothesis testing.  How does one set up the null hypothesis $H_0$ and the alternative hypothesis $H_a$?  I have read a post here that doesn't give it much credit, as far as I can tell.  (One must use both $H_0$ and $H_a$ for the AP Statistics exam.)

I have read that $H_a$ is to be what one does not want to be false (to happen).  Also, one source says that $H_0$ should always have the = sign, even when doing a one-sided (-tailed) test.  But another uses the $\geq$ and $\leq$ in $H_0$ when doing a one-sided test.  Another doesn't even mention $H_a$ and just goes straight to the P value.

Which is correct?

Question: Is A bigger than B?

$$H_0:= \left(\mu_a-\mu_b\right) = 0\quad \text{or}\quad H_0:= \left(\mu_a-\mu_b\right) \geq 0$$

$$H_a:= \left(\mu_a-\mu_b\right) \lt 0\quad \text{or}\quad H_a:= \left(\mu_a-\mu_b\right) \lt  0$$

Or is this setup better?

$$H_0:= \left(\mu_b - \mu_a\right) = 0\quad \text{or}\quad H_0:= \left(\mu_b-\mu_a\right) \leq 0 $$

$$H_a:= \left(\mu_b-\mu_a\right) \gt  0\quad \text{or}\quad H_a:= \left(\mu_b-\mu_a\right) \gt  0$$

Comment: Every one of those hypotheses is wrong. Hypotheses are about population parameters, not sample quantities.

Comment: @Glen_b How can I fix this?

Comment: For some reason, the Internet has an amazing amount of misrepresentations of hypothesis tests.  Over a decade ago I collected a few of these and [offered criticism](http://www.quantdec.com/envstats/notes/class_13/tests.htm). (It was perhaps a little harsh--every one of the statements I quoted had a grain of truth to it--but somehow I am not surprised that every one of those links is now a 404, while most of the links I found useful are still live.) That criticism may help resolve parts of the present question--but no doubt will lead to further questions :-).

Comment: Shouldn't the proposed $H_0$ be an equality not an inequality?

Comment: @whuber thank you very much, What you wrote is better than what I read.  I really hope you are a teacher because I would like to take your classes.

Comment: Mao, @Jase makes a good point: your alternative hypotheses and null hypotheses overlap in the first half of each disjunctive pair. Perhaps you intended to write "=" where you currently have "$\neq$?  (BTW, thank you for your kind words in the previous comment.)

Comment: @MaoYiyi Your hypotheses need to be about $\mu$'s (or $\theta$'s or somesuch symbols for the population means). You already know the $\bar{x}$'s differ!