# Different representations of the one-tailed/one-side hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, pearson-r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What hypothesis for A is better than B?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45825/what-hypothesis-for-a-is-better-than-b)

Consider the Pearson correlation estimate $r$. I want to do a hypothesis test.

$$\text{Option 1}$$

$H_0: \text{corr}(X,Y) \leq 0$

$H_1: \text{corr}(X,Y) > 0$

$$\text{Option 2}$$

$H_0: \text{corr}(X,Y) = 0$

$H_1: \text{corr}(X,Y) > 0$

---

I'm wondering if there's any difference between the two in terms of application (and theory)? I want to do $\text{Option 1}$ but the only information I can find is on $\text{Option 2}$.

Comment: Interestingly, exactly this question was asked just a few hours earlier (in the wider context of hypotheses in general, but the application to $r$ is immediate). The earlier, broader question will remain open--look for answers there.

Comment: @whuber That question is testing two means and also has an inequality as the null, whereas I have an equality.

Comment: That question is testing two *parameters,* Jase, and the correlation is a parameter in your setting.  It is explicitly asking whether to use an equality or inequality for the null hypothesis.  Thus the only difference I can detect is that you call your parameter "$r$" and the duplicate calls it "$\mu$".